# bash -x introduces strange quotes

Tags: bash, shell, debugging

A simple bash script named 1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo "hello, $@; "
```

When running it with:

```
$ ./1.sh --config 8888 --match 2
```

The output is:

```
+ echo 'hello, --config' 8888 --match '2; '
hello, --config 8888 --match 2;
```

`'--config'` is `$1`; `8888` is `$2`; `--match` is `$3`; and `2` is `$4`.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why double quotes introduce single quotes in debug output?
2. Why there are only 2 pairs of single quotes in debug output, not more or less?

---

**EDIT**

`'--config'` is `$1`, as @Hastur said.

Comment: Do not worry `$1` is only `--config`. Add another line in the script to check it: `echo '$1=' $1`

Comment: `$1` wouldn't change but the effect might be different depending upon how you are using `"hello, $@; "`.

Answer (score 3):

The *strange quotes* are nothing but a result of the fact the your have strings before and after the expansion of the special variable `@`.  In fact, the behavior is true for any array.

When you say:

```
echo "foo $@ bar"
```

then `foo` is interpreted to be a part of the first positional parameter and `bar` is interpreted to be a part of the last positional parameter.

The following example illustrates it better:

```
$ foo=(one two three)
+ foo=(one two three)

$ echo "${foo[@]}"
+ echo one two three
one two three

$ echo "${foo[@]} four"
+ echo one two 'three four'
one two three four

$ echo "zero ${foo[@]}"
+ echo 'zero one' two three
zero one two three

# Lets see how the resulting array is actually formed as in your example
$ for i in "zero ${foo[@]} four"; do echo $i; done
+ for i in '"zero ${foo[@]} four"'
+ echo zero one
zero one
+ for i in '"zero ${foo[@]} four"'
+ echo two
two
+ for i in '"zero ${foo[@]} four"'
+ echo three four
three four
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is `$*` not `$@`. The difference is explained well in the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_002a):

> *****
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word
>   with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of
>   the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c…",
>   where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If
>   IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null,
>   the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
>
> **@**
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …. If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, ***the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word***, and the ***expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word***. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Answer (score 0):

1. It's showing the way the command line is parsed in canonical form. Since it's showing it at a stage where no more processing will be done, it uses single quotes to represent the literal arguments.
2. Quotes are only put around the arguments that contain special characters that need to be quoted. The first argument has a space between `hello,` and `--config`, so it needs to be quoted. The last argument contains `;` and `space`, which need to be quoted. But `8888` and `--match` don't have any special characters, so no quotes are need.
3. When you put `$@` inside double quotes, it turns each of the original arguments into a separate argument. But you also have extra text around it in the quotes. The string before it gets put onto the beginning of `$1`, the string after it gets put onto the end of the last argument.

Normally you just write `"$@"`. I can't think of a reason why you would put `$@` inside another string like you do.